# Network speed varies 100Mbps or 1Gbps

Tags: networking, 16.04, transfer

**This is a question I couldn't find the answer to and finally answered myself...**

My network is doing weird things.  Usually, it runs at 1000 speeds, but when I do multiple file transfers simultaneously, it suddenly slows down to 100Mbps.  Both computers have 10/100/1000 ethernet cards and the switch also full supports 1000Mbps speeds.  What is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out this problem was caused by a ridiculously simple mistake - one of my ethernet cables was a CAT5.  It took me a while to finally suspect the cable because my network normally ran at 1Gbps.  Replacing the cable with a CAT5e fixed the problem right up.